# Ajax Jquery Request of xml data need to run in back end in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to download the top stories of the BBC website. and display them on a HTML web page. previously I tried to do this through ajax in javascript.However, I get the error that:

"XMLHTTPRequest cannot load my page as no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.cso is therefore not allowed access."

I did some more research and found that as I am doing this in Django, I need to request the object from the URL using my views.py file, not ajax.

Ive been reserching most of today, with no sucess, so was wondering if someone could help me or forward me to some links which can!

My current code is as follows:

News.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 function an(){
  $("#TopNews").append("<ul></ul>");
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function upon_success ( xml ) {
    if(response.status === "success"){
     $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
      var Titles = $(this).find('title').text(); 
      $("<li></li>").html(Titles).appendTo("#TopNews ul");
     });
    }
    else if (response.status === "error"){
     alert("The XML File could not be processed correctly.");
    }
   }
  });
 };

 $("#btn").click(an);
});
```

```html
Html:

{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/News.js" %}></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Top News: BBC versus CNN</h1>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Refresh"></imput> 
  <ul id="TopNews"></ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Views.py: [views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnn1J.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the request in views.py (your pic of views.py looks like urls.py) by using something like the [Python requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

def your_view(request):
    xml_news = requests.get('<your url>')
    news = #maybe some parsed version of your xml
    return render(request, 'your_page.html', {'news': news})
```

Then, you can change your template to include something like:

```
{% for item in news %}
   <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Otherwise, use your javascript to add the xml to your page like you have in your example.